# Function of Base Number 10 to 2,8,16 Ploblem?

Tags: c++

I Beginner to Coding and English language maybe not good. (I'm living Bangkok,Thailand)

I created Function Base number 10 to 2,8,16 by using with Switch Case.

You can see my code C++ at here :

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5d31d216c85194470def16d31a2b97cf

Ploblem

When i was run the program,i selected number Case 1 , 2 , 3 << it can't work,if i selected Case 4 to End Program is work.

I don't know that ploblem i thought write wrong code ?

Thank you.

Comment: because you didn't initialize x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Problem is, as Tyger mentioned that you didn't initialize the x, you could get that from a cin like in the menu funciton.
The other problem is that even though you get the string form the functions, you doesn't write it out. So your main function should look something like this:

```
int main(){

string out;  // Do you realy need the out string here?
int mod,x;   // or the mod here
int choice;

cout << "Give x: " << endl;
cin >> x;

out = " ";

do{
    menu(choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1 : cout << base10to2(x) << endl; break;
        case 2 : cout << base10to8(x) << endl; break;
        case 3 : cout << base10to16(x) << endl; break;
    }
}
while(choice != 4);{
cout<<"End Program / Thank You";
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Thank Geri. I forgot write Cout for Enter Base 10 to Convert any 2,8,6 in function and Output after converted. 

I can fixed the ploblem because you. 

thank you very much.